# Syntax extension using type class methods in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I want to bind a `check` method to the `Test` in such a way that the implementation does not contain an argument (look at the last line). It is necessary to use type classes here, but I'm new in Scala, so I have problems.

Object `Checker` is my attempts to solve the problem. Perhaps it is enough to make changes to it...

```
trait Test[+T] extends Iterable[T]

class TestIterable[+T](iterable: Iterable[T]) extends Test[T] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[T] = iterable.iterator
}

object Test {
  def apply[T](iterable: Iterable[T]): Test[T] = new TestIterable[T](iterable)
}

trait Check[M] {
  def check(m: M): M
}

object Checker {
  def apply[M](implicit instance: Check[M]): Check[M] = instance

  implicit def checkSyntax[M: Check](m: M): CheckOps[M] = new CheckOps[M](m)

  private implicit def test[T](m: Test[T]) : Check[Test[T]] = {
    new Check[Test[T]] {
      override def check(m: Test[T]) = m
    }
  }

  final class CheckOps[M: Check](m: M) {
    def x2: M = Checker[M].check(m)
  }
}

import Checker._

val test123 = Test(Seq(1, 2, 3))
Test(test123).check
```

Comment: You had a couple of typos a simple errors, I fixed the code [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/AEPFmiXIS3ej3HUev4SIPw/3) let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez , Now I have an error in the .scala file on CheckOps: Value class may not be a member of another class

Comment: Yeah you must define value classes either as top level or inside an object. If you define them top-level then they can not be implicit but you can define the implicit conversion. A common pattern is to define those implicit conversions inside some trait and have a couple of objects that implement those traits.  You can see a simple example of such pattern [here](https://github.com/neotypes/neotypes/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/neotypes/implicits/syntax)